# Numpy arrays assignment operations indexed with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `y` with indexes of values that must be *incremented by one* in another array `x` 
just like `x[y] += 1`, This is an example:

```
>>> x = np.zeros(5,dtype=np.int)
>>> y = np.array([1,4])
>>> x
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> x[y] += 1
>>> x
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

So far so good, but then I've this problem:

```
>>> x
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> y = np.array([1,1])
>>> x
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> x[y] += 1
>>> x
array([0, 2, 0, 0, 1])
```

I was expecting `x` to be `array([0, 3, 0, 0, 1])`: `x[1]` should be incremented by one twice, 
but I got it with `x[1]` incremented just by one.

How can I did it? Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x[y] += 1
```

is the equivalent to

```
x[y] = x[y] + 1
x[y]+1
# array([2, 2])
```

Effectively `numpy` operates on the terms in parallel, not sequentially.

```
x[y]=[4,3]  # or
x[y] += [4,3]
```

suggests that if different values are assigned to the same term, it is the last action that one has effect (but that probably isn't guaranteed).

---

```
np.add.at(x,y,1)
```

does what you expect.

from the documentation for `np.add.at`:

> For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to
>   `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements that
>   are indexed more than once. For example, `a[[0,0]] += 1` will only
>   increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas
>   `add.at(a, [0,0], 1)` will increment the first element twice.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
>>> x=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> y=np.array([1,4])
>>> x+=np.bincount(y, minlength=x.size)
>>> x
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> y=np.array([1,1])
>>> x+=np.bincount(y, minlength=x.size)
>>> x
array([0, 3, 0, 0, 1])
>>> map(id, x[y])
[20481944, 20481944]
```

`x[1,1]` only references the same element, `+1` therefore only act on one element.